# Avoid multiple if-else statements in a factory class [language agnostic]

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I have some data that I'm trying to sift through and I can't figure out a smart way of doing this. Let's say I have 3 types:

A, B, C and they all extend a class S.

If I create a factory that just creates and returns and object of type S, it seems like it would be very procedural. The factory's implementation in pseudo-code would be something like this:

```
class Factory {
    func create_obj(input_data) -> S {
        if type(input_data) is A {
            return A()
        }
        else if type(input_data) is B {
            return B()
        }
        else {
            return C()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a lot of different data types that it could possibly be. That means this algorithm in the worst case is in quadratic time. Is there a better solution, design pattern, or any optimizations I can look at? To be more specific, I'm creating instances of certain data types and the input is lines of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach the problem would be to use a pre-populated [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(associative_array)) where the key is a [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)) representing a line/value in the file and the value is the object that should be returned for that line.

**Sample implementation :**

Let `file` be an asscociateive array. On startup, the factory should pre-populate this array with *string* to object mappings :

```
files["A"] = new A();
files["B"] = new B();
files["C"] = new C();
```

The factory can then be passed a *string* which it will lookup in the associative array to fetch the corresponding pre-populated object :

```
func create_obj(input_data) -> S {
   return files[input_data];
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution implies you always get the same A instance

Comment: One can easily extend this solution to always return a new instance and there are several ways to achieve this depending on the language being used. The crux of the solution remains the same i.e, use associative arrays to avoid if-else in a factory class.